# How to add an additional binary variable with CPLEX and Python?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex

I have an integer programming problem with a decision variable `X_i_j_k_t` that is 1 if job `i` was assigned to worker `j` for day `k` and shift `t`. I am maximizing the benefit of assigning orders to my workers. I have an additional binary variable `Y_i_k_t` that is 1 if the job was executed and a given day and shift (jobs might require more than one worker). How can I add this variable in CPLEX? So as to form, for example, `sum(i, k, t)(Y_i_k_t) <= 1` (the order can´t be done more than once).

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please consider reading the How to Ask section of the site. Please post the *code* you have tried out so far, and include any **specific** error cases that you are getting stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

You did not say whether you use the CPLEX Python API or docplex. But in either case, you can call the functions that create variables multiple times.

So in the CPLEX Python API call `Cplex.variables.add()` again to add another set of variables.

In docplex just call `Model.binary_var_dict()` (or whatever method you used to create `X`) again for the Y variables.

Comment: I am sorry. I am using the CPLEX Python API. So, with cplex.variables.add() I can add that binary variable? I'm not sure how exactly to do it.

Comment: Can you augment your question with the code that creates the X variable? Then I can show you how to analogously create the Y variables.

Comment: my_problem.variables.add(obj = coeficientes_funcion_objetivo, lb = [0]*data.n, ub = [1]*data.n, types=['B']*data.n). Where "coeficientes_funcion_objetivo" is my list with the benefit of each order per needed worker.

Comment: The functions returns the indices of the X variables. Now do the same to create Y variables and get their indices. Maybe take a look at the examples that ship with CPLEX. There are several examples that create multiple types of variables. For example, `admipex8.py` which creates variables called `supply` and `cost`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, thanks! The objective function of this problem is maximize the benefit minus the cost. These are two different sums. How can I do thiis with CPLEX Python API?

Comment: In the CPLEX Python API you define an objective using `Cplex.objective.set_linear()`. With this you set the objective function coefficient for each variable. So for the sum to be subtracted you just set negative coefficients.